# how to configure SMTP in codeigniter application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I'm new to `SMTP`, `sendmail`, and `mail()` function in php codeigniter.

I'm trying to configure SMTP mail protocol in my codeigniter application. Make all settings, SMTP port, sender mail, user id, password for single user i.e. `admin@example.com`. It working fine.

My question is, it is possible to setup two SMTP user account in single application ?

For example I want to set `info@example`.com and `admin@example.com`, so these two users can send mails to customers.

Comment: Can you show me your sendmail function code snippest ?

Comment: Everything is possible, unless you're talking quantum mechanics on a normal CPU. But all that, requires code and I'm not seeing any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it by only changes in config : as like

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx', // First user authenticate
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.

$result = $this->email->send();
```

and

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'yyy', // Second user authenticate
    'smtp_pass' => 'zzzz',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.

$result = $this->email->send();
```

But only one thing is that you have to configure your both mail user at server. Thanks