# CodeIgniter not sending emails with SMTP

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am using my domain details for sending the emails with CodeIgniter SMTP, but emails are not going. This is my settings:

```
 $full_name =  'xxx';
 $from = $email = 'info@manazelspecilists.com';
 $configs = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'mail.manazelspecialists.ae',
      'smtp_port' => 587,
      'smtp_user' => 'support@manazelspecialists.ae',
      'smtp_pass' => 'xxxx',
      'mailtype' => 'html',
      'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
      'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

$this->load->library('email', $configs);
$this->email->initialize($configs);

$msg = '<html><body>';
$msg.= 'msg here';
$msg.= '</body></html>';

$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->subject('Career Form Filled');
$this->email->from($from,$full_name);
$this->email->reply_to(REPLY_TO);
$this->email->to('xxxx@gmail.com');
$this->email->message($msg);
$this->email->send();
```

and I am receiving this error: Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error:
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Comment: Are you trying this code with your localhost or with live server?

Comment: I am trying this on live server, with smtp.googlemail.com  its working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to configure SMTP in codeigniter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973704/how-to-configure-smtp-in-codeigniter-application)

Comment: @dev, With googlemail.com you would be using port `'smtp_port' => 465`?

Comment: Yes @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: @dev : can you please  insert 'newline' => "\r\n",  on your  config  array and check

Comment: ok @dev, you need to check if port `587` is open with your live server or not.

Comment: if your problem solved than you have to select atleast one answer.

Answer (score 2):

change one line in the config array and try

```
 $configs = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://mail.manazelspecialists.ae',//change here
      'smtp_port' => 587,
      'smtp_user' => 'support@manazelspecialists.ae',
      'smtp_pass' => 'xxxx',
      'mailtype' => 'html',
      'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
      'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );
```

Comment: Thank you @anand Panday, its working now, its going in spam and 'mailtype' => 'html' is not effecting. Its sending raw email.

Answer (score 1):

I think nothing is wrong with the code. You need to make sure to set up the right configs of your mail server.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `smtp_port` to 25

```
$config = Array();

 $config['protocol']        = 'smtp';
 $config['smtp_host']       = 'mocha4004.mochahost.com';
 $config['smtp_port']       = '25';
 $config['smtp_user']       = 'ankits@iguru-india.com';
 $config['smtp_pass']       = 'ankit123';
 $config['mailtype']        = 'html';
 $config['charset']         = 'iso-8859-1';
 $config['wordwrap']        = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try my example

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->model('email_model');
}


public function emails()
{

    $data['emails']=$this->email_model->get_records_of_chats_with_clients();
    $this->load->view('templates/head', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('email/view_emails', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');


}
public function create()
{
    $data['privileges'] = $this->email_model->get_privileges();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('privilege', 'privilege', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('from_name', 'from_name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('from_email', 'from_email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('to_email', 'to_email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $this->load->view('templates/head', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('email/create_email', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
    $this->email_model->record_chats_with_clients();
    redirect('email/emails');
    }

}
public function kurti(){
    $data['privileges'] = $this->email_model->get_privileges();
    $email_to=$this->input->post('to_email');
    $name_input=$this->input->post('name');
    $name_session=$this->session->userdata('name');
    $title=$this->input->post('title');
    $message=$this->input->post('message');
    if(!isset($name_input)){
        $name=$name_session;
    } else{
        $name=$name_input;
    }

    $this->email->from('mantas@fastfood.lt', $name);
    $this->email->to($email_to);
    $this->email->subject($title);
    $this->email->message($message);
    $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'example.serveriai.lt',
        'smtp_port' => 587,
        'smtp_user' => 'mantas@fastfood.lt',
        'smtp_pass' => 'example',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $this->load->library('email', $config);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('to_email', 'Gavėjo adresas', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Gavėjo žinutės tema', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Žinutė', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $this->load->view('templates/head');
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('email/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } elseif ($this->email->send()) {
        $this->email_model->record_chats_with_clients($name);
        $message = "success";
        echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">alert(\''.$message.'\');
        window.location = \'/email/emails\';</script>';
    }
    else
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('admin'=='1')){
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());

        } else{
            $message = "error!";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }

    }
}
```